# Question about Probability, Moment Generating Functions and Discrete Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let analyze the Moment Generating Function

$M(t)= 0.3 e^{t} + 0.4 e^{2t} + 0.2 e^{3t} + 0.1 e^{4t}$

Here is the question:

***Give the name of the distribution of X, if it has a name.***

Analyzing the Moment Generating Function, we can conclude that

P(1)= 0.3

P(2)= 0.4

P(3)= 0.2

P(4)= 0.1

Adding all of them we get 1, then we have probability mass function(pmf).

[image]

Now, I am comparing the Moment Generating function with all the ones that are listed in this formula sheet.

***In my perspective, it does not match any of them. Am I correct?***

***I also have a second question:***

In this case for me, the fact that the Moment Generating Function is not defined to x=0 shows that we do not have also a Hypergeometric Function. But, as in the cheat sheet there is no Moment Generating Function for the Hypergeometric Function, does that possibility exist?

Here is the cheat-sheet of Discrete Distributions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is just a particular discrete distribution which does not belongs to any simple, well known discrete distribution family, so it is not surprising that it does not match into any one of them in your text. Also hypergeometric distribution is a bounded distribution, so all of its moments, and its mgf exist. But its mgf does not have a closed-form, which is ugly and thus usually the elementary text may just skip this.

Comment: @BGM Amazing ideas! Your comment is really an answer.... Why you did not post it as an answer? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @BGM One question, would you agree with my comment that "the fact that the Moment Generating Function is not defined to x=0 shows that we do not have also a Hypergeometric Function"?